# What's the relationship between thread and queue in GCD?

Tags: ios

1. does one thread only contain one queue?
2. if I dispatch a block asynchronously to globalQueue ,can it run on main thread by any chance?
3. what kind of situation will cause `dispatch_sync` to dead lock?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***1. Does one thread only contain one queue?***

The relationship is one way. Serial queue may hold a thread to execute the block dispatched to it, but thread doesn't know a queue. Well, main thread is special, it knows the main queue.

***My guess***

Dispatch queue doesn't indicate which thread it will run block or function on, I think dispatch queue manages a thread pool which contains many thread, it will fetch one idle thread when a block is dispatched. So one thread may work for many dispatch queue in a period time.

But one think is for sure: when you dispatch a block to a queue, the thread which this block is running on works for one determined dispatch queue, you can get it using `dispatch_get_current_queue`.

***2. If I dispatch a block asynchronously to globalQueue ,can it run on main thread by any chance?***

I think it won't run any block to globalQueue on main thread, because it can't evaluate the execution time of the block, if it is a long time job, it will block the main thread.

***3. what kind of situation will cause dispatch_sync to dead lock?***

I reference the paragraph in `Concurrency programming guide`

> You should never call the dispatch_sync or dispatch_sync_f function
>   from a task that is executing in the same queue that you are planning
>   to pass to the function. This is particularly important for serial
>   queues, which are guaranteed to deadlock, but should also be avoided
>   for concurrent queues.

Comment: I think #2 is also true because otherwise you could easily create a deadlock (#3) using `dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue...` from your queue running on the main thread on globalQueue.